# Can't connect to networks, wireless or etho, after installing Ubuntu 12.10 on vostro 1500

Tags: 12.10, troubleshooting

I am a very inexperienced Linux user and don't really know what I'm doing. I recently updated to Ubuntu 12.10 with a live disk on my vostro 1500 laptop. The network was not connected when I updated to the newer operating system. Now my desktop can connect to any network. I tried using my eithernet cable to go and download a chunk of missing firmware, but my computer won't connect to the eithernet either. What do I do here? 
Basic advice would be much appriciated as I am not well acquainted with using terminal. 
Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

write results of 
`ifconfig`
for start
so that we can see what is running. 
if it doesnt show any eth0, then add the outcome of `lspci` and `lsmod`

I know that there is no network so paste it on a key

if it shows eth, plug it in and go to network manage. alow wired network.

Comment: Typing that in does not show etho. However typing in the next two commands you suggested brings up a lengthy page or so of code.. I am working from an iPhone, so I wonder if there is any way I can send you pictures of terminal as opposed to rewriting it? Thanks so much..

Comment: ťall I need is the one which includes network something.  you can try to make picture using prtscr, but then you have to transfer  alternatively just use camera to make it

Comment: I posted the results of those two commands here: http://mvshroom.tumblr.com/post/51995659506/results-for-commands-in-terminal-thanks-for-the

Comment: this is he same problem as this one http://askubuntu.com/questions/302903/ubuntu-13-04-64bit-wi-fi-not-detecting-any-networks/302941?noredirect=1#comment381551_302941

Comment: use this guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper 
in your case 2.1.3 apply

Comment: I tried this but I am missing a package manager on my computer.

Comment: use apt instead